# Sklearn model sagemaker deployememt gives No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker, knn

I am trying to deploy the Knn model on Sagemaker but getting the error below. I have tried downgrading the Python version to 3.8.16 and my Sagemaker kernel has the same Python version but am not able to crack it.

Below is the code for entry point to perform inference
**model_script.py**

```
import os
import joblib
import json


def model_fn(model_dir):
    model = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir,'KNN_model.joblib'))
    vectorizer = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, 'vectorizer.joblib'))
    book_data = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir,'book_data.joblib'))
    return model,vectorizer,book_data

 

# Preprocess input data and perform nearest neighbor search
def predict(input_data, model, vectorizer, book_data):
    input_json = json.loads(input_data)
    book_titles = input_json["book_titles"]

 

    # Preprocess input data using the loaded vectorizer
    input_vectors = vectorizer.transform(book_titles)

 

    # Perform nearest neighbor search using the k-NN model
    neighbors = model.kneighbors(input_vectors, n_neighbors=5, return_distance=False)

 

    # Return the neighbors as a JSON response
    response = {"neighbors": neighbors.tolist()}
    return json.dumps(response)

has context menu
```

below is my aws sagemaker deployment scriot

**deploy.ipynb**

```
model = SKLearnModel(model_data=f's3://{bucket_name}/model.tar.gz',
                     role=role,
                     entry_point='model_script.py',
                     framework_version='1.0-1',
                     py_version='py3')

 

predictor = model.deploy(instance_type='ml.m5.large', initial_instance_count=1)
predictor.wait()
```

ERROR :
updated on 7th aug:

- at the time of deserializing model in model_fn joblib.load is throwing error of module not found of scipy.

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 55, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 143, in handle_request
    super().handle_request(listener_name, req, sock, addr)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 106, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 127, in main
    user_module_transformer, execution_parameters_fn = import_module(serving_env.module_name,
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 113, in import_module
    user_module_transformer.initialize()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_transformer.py", line 185, in initialize
    self._model = self._model_fn(_env.model_dir)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 95, in wrapper
    six.reraise(error_class, error_class(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 93, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/ml/code/model_script.py", line 17, in model_fn
    model = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir,'KNN_model.joblib'))
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 658, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 577, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1212, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1537, in load_stack_global
    self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1579, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)

 

sagemaker_containers._errors.ClientError: No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'
```

Comment: Please update your post to include the full error trace (the message you mention in your title is nowhere to be seen in the body)

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut I have added the details let me know if you required more

Comment: Please do not post screenshots - post the error message as *text*; see how to make a [mre]

Comment: @desertnaut added the text

Comment: Try `framework_version ="1.2-1"`

Comment: but at the time of building KNN, i used the version of scikit-learn is 1.0.1

Comment: @alvas tried that version but facing the same error.

Comment: Seems like an issue with Anaconda and miniconda3, locally it shows the anaconda3 version when I use pip show. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This error - `No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'`- tells that the required module from the scipy library isn't available in the environment in which you're trying to deploy your model.

You can create a custom Docker image built on top of what Sagemaker uses, configure it to have all the additional libraries you installed locally and use that.

Here's how you'd do that.

#### Get your dependecies

You can use the following command if you need to know your dependencies to see all installed packages.

```bash
pip3 list
```

#### Create the `Dockerfile`

```
# Use the SageMaker Scikit-learn image as the base
FROM <ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.<REGION_NAME>.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-scikit-learn:<SCIKIT-LEARN_VERSION>-cpu-py<PYTHON_VERSION>

# Uninstall the current scipy version (if present) and install the desired version and other dependencies
RUN pip uninstall -y scipy && pip install scipy==YOUR_VERSION <ANY OTHER STUFF>

# Set up the entry point for the training script
ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM model_script.py
```

Now, build the Docker image:

```bash
docker build -t custom-sagemaker-image .
```

#### Push the Image to Amazon ECR

**Note:** *Before this, you must create a repository in Amazon ECR to store your custom image.*

```bash
docker tag custom-sagemaker-image:latest YOUR_ECR_REPO:latest
docker push YOUR_ECR_REPO:latest
```

#### Deploy using the Custom Docker Container

When deploying your model using SageMaker, use your custom image URI (from ECR) instead of the default SageMaker Scikit-learn image.

```py
from sagemaker.model import Model

model = Model(model_data=f's3://{bucket_name}/model.tar.gz',
             role=role,
             entry_point='model_script.py',
             image_uri='YOUR_ECR_REPO:latest')

predictor = model.deploy(instance_type='ml.m5.large', initial_instance_count=1)
```